# Is it possible to skip all animations in Mario Party 10?

Tags: mario-party-10

I just got Mario Party 10 and want to play the 5 players games. Currently we're playing board games and it's so annoying having all these animations.

Is there an option to turn animations off so dice rolls are instantaneous? This way we'll just play games and stop all this pointless animation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to skip the animations.But if you go to from the main menu to bowser party then to minigames you can just play the minigames.